# Need to group the apps under labels for the sidebar of django admin using the package jazzmin

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I have managed to group the apps in the landaing page of dashboard. But in side bar it was not refelcting. i need to group the models in the **side bar** too.

i have used the **jazzmin** package as well as the **admin_reorder**

packages used are :-
django-modeladmin-reorder==0.3.1 and
django-reorder-admin==0.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom middleware and add it in your settings file.

```
from admin_reorder.middleware import ModelAdminReorder


class ModelAdminReorderWithNav(ModelAdminReorder):

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):

        available_apps = response.context_data.get('available_apps')

        response.context_data['app_list'] = available_apps

        response = super().process_template_response(request, response)

        response.context_data['available_apps'] = response.context_data[

            'app_list'

        ]

        return response
```

Comment: https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder/issues/47

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the current reorder package - it looks like it is not maintained. I had exactly the same issue but I found that a PR exists, that solves this issue.

You can navigate to the [issue](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder/issues/47#issuecomment-674782623) and fetch the lib through a github repo, instead of using it directly under the package name.

Hope it helps.